elasticsearch query multiple map and only return if atleast 1 value in every map is satisfied
I have a field in my doc that could contain multiple map like this
"allCodesRequired": [
  {
    "mapKey1": ["one", "two"]
  },
  {
    "mapKey2": ["foo", "bar"]
  }
]

each of the value in every map must be match. So if I have a query value like this ["one", "bar"] it should return the doc, but if I only have a query value like this ["one"] it will fail since one is not exist in map 2.
Also the map count in the doc is not fixed, it could be 1 or 2 or 3 etc
I have tried using multi match with cross field, but with query value like this ["one"] it will still return the doc for above case.
Here is the query that I tried
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "one",
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "fields":     [ "allCodesRequired.*" ],
      "operator":   "and"
    }
  }
}

UPDATE
I tried using script query, but apparently it doesn't support for nested objects.
